# Tomcat web.xml configuration variables

Tags: tomcat, servlets, configuration, web.xml

My Java web application includes a configuration file (e.g. myapp.xml) in the war file. I provide the path to this file in my web.xml file as follows.

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>wc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.servlets.WC</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>configfile</param-name>
      <param-value>${catalina.base}/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/myapp.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

The problem is that I now want to deploy various versions on the same server for testing and development and each will have a different path under webapps. I want to avoid modifying the web.xml file for each deployment, but I can't find any way to reference the WEB-INF folder.

This is what I would like to do:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>wc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.servlets.WC</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>configfile</param-name>
      <param-value>${app.base}/myapp.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

Where **${app.base} == ${catalina.base}/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF**

Is there some available variable that would give me the path to the application directory?

If not, can you think of some other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the variable with `-Dapp.base=/foo/bar` to tomcat's JVM (depending on the version either in catalina.sh or in a file in /conf), and then read it with `System.getProperty(..) in your WC servlet.

Although it is advisable to put these configurations to an external location, so that you can change them without touching the deployed application, and also to enable unpacked WAR deployment, if needed.

If you want to access a resource within the application, then you'd better work with relative (rather than absolute) paths.

- if the resource is on the classpath, use `getClass().getResourceAsAstream(..)`
- if the resource is outside the classpath, use `servletContext.getResourceAsStream(..)`

Comment: I know I can give tomcat variables like that, but that doesn't answer my question. I want to reference the path to the currently deployed application in the web.xml for that application. With this solution I would have to provide variables for all anticipated deployments and still modify the web.xml to reference the variable related to that anticipated deployment.

Comment: Why do you need the absolute path? You can (and should) work with relative paths. See my update

Comment: Thanks for your update. What you show would allow me to access application resources in code, but I'm not sure how I would translate that into something I could put in my web.xml to reference the myapp.xml...

Comment: you can't. But as you will be reading this parameter in the code anyway, you can put that logic there, rather than the xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
...
servletContext().getRealPath("");
...
```

to get the phyical main directory of you application.

Comment: This would allow me to get the path in the code of my application, but no from the web.xml.